# android:allowBackup=false but BackupAgent still required

Tags: android, backup-agent

I busy designing an app (Android Studio 1.3.1) for Android ver 4.4.2 and would like the app to be started immediately after boot-up. My problem is that it doesn't and on debugging I found that it complains about a missing BackupAgent. I have set android:allowBackup to false in the manifest but this doesn't seem to help remove the exception about the missing BackupAgent.

Am I miss-understanding the purpose of android:allowBackup?

I don't require any backing up.

Answer (score 0):

**Seems like those are different from eachother:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

```
<application android:allowTaskReparenting=["true" | "false"]
             android:allowBackup=["true" | "false"]
             android:backupAgent="string"
```

And:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent.html

> ***Provides the central interface between an application and Android's
>   data backup infrastructure***. An application that wishes to participate
>   in the backup and restore mechanism will declare a subclass of
>   BackupAgent, implement the onBackup() and onRestore() methods, and
>   provide the name of its backup agent class in its AndroidManifest.xml
>   file via the `<application>` tag's android:backupAgent attribute.

And you need to add this in your `ApplicationTAG -> Manifest`:

```
android:backupAgent
```

---

**Also, you may want to take a look:**

Most applications shouldn't need to extend the ***BackupAgent class directly***, but should instead extend BackupAgentHelper to take advantage of the built-in helper classes that automatically backup and restore your files. However, you might want to extend BackupAgent directly if you need to:

- Version your data format. For instance, if you anticipate the need to
  revise the format in which you write your application data, you can
  build a backup agent to cross-check your application version during a
  restore operation and perform any necessary compatibility work if the
  version on the device is different than that of the backup data. For
  more information, see Checking the [Restore Data Version](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#RestoreVersion).
- Instead of backing up an entire file, you can specify the portions of
  data the should be backed up and how each portion is then restored to
  the device. (This can also help you manage different versions,
  because you read and write your data as unique entities, rather than
  complete files.)
- Back up data in a database. If you have an SQLite database that you
  want to restore when the user re-installs your application, you need
  to build a custom [BackupAgent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent.html) that reads the appropriate data during
  a backup operation, then create your table and insert the data during
  a restore operation.